# What's the exact meaning of a decree?

Tags: meaning

At first, I thought it just meant an "order", yet it didn't make much sense in the context it was in.

I was watching a historical TV show, in which a powerful man, an ally of the King (not really an ally, but more of a follower whom the King needs), was telling the King of a near attack of the enemy. He told the King to "**speak his decree, and it will be done"**. The King replied "there's no need for decrees, nor sermons to rouse. We march, before they do".
Then, the ally asked the king to let *him* lead the assault, if not, he will abandon the King. The King was furious, he told him that he doesn't need him, and banished him. Then, the ally told the King that while the King marches to the enemy, he will march towards their true capital, and defend it. Then the King said: "**No one asked you to make a decree, yet you do so here before *my* throne**?"

From my understanding, the word *decree* means, as stated by [The Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/official):

> *1 An official order that has the force of law*
>
> *1.2 A judgement or decision of certain law courts, especially in matrimonial cases.*

I've also checked several other dictionaries, they basically give the same definitions. My problem is that none of the given definitions fits in any of the two sentences.
Look at the first sentence, the King said "we march", which *is* an order (or would at least require him to make orders in order to march), but that was right after he said "there is no need for decrees". If so, the King must think that a *decree* is different than a simple *order*. After that, look at the second sentence, the King accused his ally of "making a *decree*", but the ally did not make any decrees\orders (by my understanding). And if he did, it wasn't official, the whole conversation took place in the same place, the King's court. So, if something the ally said was a decree, then the King's statement must also be a decree; they were said in the same manner, and in the same place.

This is the script for the scene I speak of, if anyone wants to read it themselves:

> (Kaidu): The Cricket Minister comes this way.
>   His troops are mobilizing.
>   War is upon us once again.
>   **Speak your decree**, cousin.
>   It will be done.
>   
> (The Khan): **There's no need for decrees**.
>   Or sermons to rouse.
>   We march before they do.
>   Go.
>   
> (Kaidu): By your will, Sire.
>   And by the House of ÃgÃdei, I will lead your tumens.
>   
> (The Khan): Praises, cousin.
>   You will ride with our tumens and my sons.
>   I name you commander of 1,000 men.
>   But I lead this assault.
>   You ride with the House of Kublai.
>   
> (Kaidu): I am grateful for the honor, Khagan.
>   But hear me, please, cousin.
>   Twice my men and horses have ridden under your banner.
>   Twice my men and two sons have fallen to the Chinese.
>   If I do not lead this next assault my men will return north, and I with them.
>   
> (The Khan's Son): Lord Kaidu, there's no need to rush.
>   
> (The Khan): Let him rush.
>   Let him rush home to be king of his ger village.
>   King of nomads and sheep.
>   
> (Kaidu): You mock nomads? You mock Genghis? I mock cowards, no one else.
>   Confer with your astrologers, cousin.
>   Confer with your Chinese monks, your Taoist priests.
>   Look to your Muslim imams and all your prophets.
>   How goes the Latin's construction project? My understanding from our engineers-- 
> (The Khan): My engineers! (Kaidu) My understanding from your engineers is that it is a gamble.
>   - A fool's gamble! - 
>   
> (The Khan's Son): Mind your treason! 
>   (Kaidu): Know this! As you lead your sons back into the jaws of Sidao's China I will march north to Karakorum to defend the true Mongol capital.
>   
> (The Khan): No one asked you **to make a decree**, yet you do so here before the throne of the Khan of Khans? I do not need your horses, Kaidu! I do not need your House of ÃgÃdei! Leave here.
>   You are forever banished.

Comment: “At first, I thought it just meant an ‘order’ . . .” But what did you think after consulting a dictionary or three?

Comment: I *did* consult every dictionary I know, and I did my best before asking. But wait, you mean that it means something else? What?

Comment: I think you just need to cut the definition (and the script) a little slack.

Comment: Interpreting @BrianDonovan's excellent coment, it helps us help you if you show the results of your work. Just quoting a TV show you saw doesn't tell us anything about what you found after looking it up, and, more importantly to you, **not showing the results of your research is a reason to close your question.** It's as simple as editing in the definition (and its source) and pointing out the confusion. Proofreading TV scripts is an unprofitable pursuit.

Comment: In English, Decree has multiple similar meanings and I'm not entirely sure how I should express my sentiments exactly or I'd write a fully answer.  In my own words I might define it as "a declaration of what shall be done based upon the issuer's authority ", emphasizing declaration. I recommend checking the C.D.C's. definitions of [decree](https://wordnik.com/words/decree) and [promulgate](https://wordnik.com/words/promulgate), as well as W.R.U.D. 1913's definition of [edict](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=edict&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on), which is a close synonym..

Comment: In light of the time of year for celebrants of Christmas: from the Gospel of Luke, chapter two:  "Now in those days a decree went out from Caesar Augustus, that a census be taken of all the inhabited earth. This was the first census taken while Quirinius was governor of Syria. And everyone was on his way to register for the census, each to his own city" (vv.1-3).

Comment: @medica, I didn't show the result of my work because I didn't think it would be necessary, it would only make it more complicated. I also thought it would be a bit annoying. Anyway, I edited my post and added the result of research.

Comment: It seems to me that "a declaration (from a suitably empowered individual) that has the force of law or of an order that must be followed" is a pretty accurate interpretation of the word _decree_ as it is used (multiple times) in the excerpt. Are you still unclear about anything regarding the word _decree_ and how it is used in the quoted text at this point? If so, please specify what you see as the remaining problem or mystery. Thanks!

Comment: @Sven Yargs, Thank *you*. But no, it's clear to me now thanks to Michael's posts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your initial thought about the word is correct. There is no metaphor involved.

When there was no written rule/law, *an official order* given by a person with power was a [decree](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decree) (**final decision that no one could challenge**). Also, it meant:

> a judicial decision of ***the Roman emperor***

Now, in the show *Marco Polo*, The Khan is the supreme leader of the nation/country, grandson of Ghengis Khan. Then, whatever he utters should be considered as an **official order/decree** as if they were given by **the Roman emperor, or the Pope, or God** as he is the most powerful man.

Now, in your context:

> There's no need for decrees.

It means The Cricket Minister's troops marching towards the Khan is not so important a matter that it doesn't require any decree. (In the show, The Cricket Minister doesn't have a strong army compared with the Khan's force and it is being dismissed as a trivial threat.) "We march before they do, go" is just a simple order. **A decree is given to a more important matter**.

> No one asked you to make a decree, yet you do so here before my
>   throne?

It means that you are acting **as if you had any authority to make a decree**. You can't make a decree (final decision) until you return to home and become king of his village. **King of nomads and sheep**. You are not in a position to decide who will lead the army and whether you can march north to Karakorum to defend the true Mongol capital. Only the Khan makes a decree on that. **You are being rude in front of the Khan**.

Khaidu said just before the quote:

> As you lead your sons back into the jaws of Sidao's China **I will march**
>   north to Karakorum to defend the true Mongol capital.

The whole context supports this explanation that only the Khan could make any decree. Therefore, the decree is the **Khan's order** that is **final and no one can object to it**.

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 1):

The way it is being used in your context is odd indeed. A decree comes from the French word "décret" which then again comes from the Latin word "decretum", which means nothing else than decision. Basically, it is a legal English term for a decision made by a legal authority such as a King, a president or a commission.
Nowadays it usually has a very official and ceremonial connotation.
But in the middle age for instance, any statement of the King regarding a specific matter could be considered a decree.

Answer (score 0):

The word is being used in the sense of an "order" as in "to tell someone what to do with force and in a demanding way."

The word is not being used in the way it is "normally" used.  We normally use it to describe what kings, queens, emperors, and other rulers / dictators tell their subjects.  So, when the king says "No one asked you to make a decree...", he is, in a way, accusing the ally of acting like a king, something that is not his place to do.  People don't usually give decrees to kings.  You don't negotiate with the king or give him orders.  You don't tell a king, "You need to do this and if not, I will do do this."

Words can be used outside of their dictionary definition for the purposes of humor, sarcasm, or to extend a metaphor.  For example, a wife could give her husband a decree and also use decree "language:" "Thou shalt make the bed every morning or suffer the penalty of loneliness."

Understanding this idea will help you understand, songs, poems, humor, and conversation in general.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your post was most helpful, I get it now.

Comment: I'm happy to help.  My colleagues have trouble understanding that the dictionary cannot fully help with many language problems and also don;t understand that seeing how native speakers use words outside of their normal proper usage is difficult for non-native speakers.  Fell free to ask other questions.

Comment: The way Kaidu is speaking is not considered respectful.  You don't tell the Khan "Know this..."  If Kaidu's language had been more respectful, the Khan would not have accused Kaidu of making a decree.

Comment: You took the words right of my mouth (or my head I guess). But I'm sorry, I have just one question: It all makes sense, but why did the King say the phrase "No one asked you" specifically? His phrasing there was kinda awkward to me. Was the King trying to demonstrate their difference of ranks as in "you do not even get to make orders until *I* ask you to do so"?

Comment: He could have simply said "How dare you make a decree to your king" or something like that.

Comment: It's hard to say why the actors are saying what they are saying.  The dialogue reads a bit awakward and "translated" to me.  I would have to see the program and know more about the characters to get a better idea of what's going on.  He could have said "How dare you..." however this creates a different feeling and mood.  It points out audacity and disrespect in a direct way that the other phrase, "No one..." doesn't.

Comment: You make a very compelling point. Hmm, "translated"? I would have never thought of that. XD -- On a different note: I do recommend you watch it, Marco Polo is a great show.